# Show that $(2^{a}-1)\mod(2^{b}-1) = 2^{a\mod b} - 1$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm working though the Discrete Mathematics text by Rosen and I'm stuck at this problem that says:

Show that if a and b are positive integers, then $(2^{a}-1)\mod(2^{b}-1) = 2^{a\mod b} - 1$


So far I tried substituting $a = b\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\rfloor + a\mod b$ which yields $2^{b\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\rfloor} \cdot 2^{a\mod b} - 1$ but I can't seem to get anywhere... Does  $2^{b\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\rfloor}$ get canceled or something?

 

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Hint: what is $2^b \pmod{2^b-1}$?

Comment: Hmm I think I got it lemme know if I'm right: 
$2^{b\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\rfloor} mod (2^{b}-1) = (2^{b} mod(2^{b}-1))^{\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\rfloor} = 1^{\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\rfloor} = 1$

Comment: Yes, that's the idea!

Comment: Nice, thanks alot!